# segmentation fault after a new line

Tags: c, segmentation-fault, coredump

I'm running in to a segmentation fault on the line enclosed with ****.
I pipe this output:
|status: OK|
|version: 0.85|
|author: PBrooks|
|nitems: 0|

in to my code below and it gives me a segmentation fault after I print out the '\n' in my printf statement. I don't know how to debug this though.. Does anyone have a clue?

```
#include <stdio.h> 
#include <stdlib.h> 
#include <string.h> 
#include <time.h> 


char string[300];

struct NameValue {
    char *name;
    char *value;
};

struct NameValue *pairs;

void ReadStdin(int argc, char *argv) {
    int x;

    fread(string, sizeof (char), 300, stdin);
    printf("%s\n", string);

}

void ParseInput() {
    int x, num = 0; //figure out how many i need 
    for (x = 0; x < 300; x++) {
        if (string[x] == '|') {
            num++;
        }
    }
    num /= 2; //num = how many i need 
    pairs = (malloc(num)); //allocate the array 
    int pipe = 0, i, j = 0, tempCounter = 0;
    char tempName[50], tempValue[50];
    printf("%lu \n", sizeof (string) / sizeof (string[0]));
    if (pairs != 0) {
        for (i = 0; i <= num; i++) { //counts pairs 
            printf("i = %i\n", i);
            printf("j = %i, pipe: %i \n", j, pipe);
            if (string[j] == '|') {
                printf("there's a pipe\n");
                pipe++;
                j++;
            }

            while (string[j] != ':') {
                printf("counter for main string: %i\n tempCounter: %i\n", j, tempCounter);
                tempName[tempCounter] = string[j];
                tempCounter++;
                j++;
                if (string[j] == ':') {
                    tempName[tempCounter] = '\0';
                    tempCounter = 0;
                    **printf("~~~~tempName\n is: %s", tempName);**
                    break;
                }
            }
            while (string[j] != '|') {
                j++;
                tempValue[tempCounter] = string[j];
                tempCounter++;
                if (string[j] == '|') {
                    tempValue[tempCounter] = '\0';
                    tempCounter = 0;
                    strcpy(pairs[i].value, tempValue);
                    pipe++;
                    break;
                }
            }
        }
    }
}

int main(int argc, char *argv) {
    ReadStdin(argc, argv);
    ParseInput();

    return (EXIT_SUCCESS);
}
```

edit: Sorry! I removed the null terminate character line by accident. It is in there but it's still giving me the error.

edit: a bit more information: The j variable gets incremented up to 6 and and the temp counter gets incremented up to 5 before the program spits out a segmentation fault.

Comment: `pairs = (malloc(num)); //allocate the array` what is pairs ?

Comment: Pairs is a pointer to the structure that has char* name and value. I then use malloc to make it point to an array (my wording might not be right but I hope you get the idea)

Comment: I see: it is a global pointer. but `pairs = (malloc(num)); //allocate the array ` , dis you intend: `pairs = malloc(num * sizeof *pairs);` ?

Comment: I wanted to allocate enough pairs for the output from the other program. In this case I get 4 lines of text so I made malloc'd 4 pairs.

Comment: Wrong: you malloc()d four _characters_. Remember: malloc() counts in characters. Malloc has **no idea** about what you want. It just counts in characters. Fortunately, sizeof also counts in terms of characters.

Comment: Hmm.. I just tried pairs = malloc(num * sizeof *pairs); and it still doesn't work. I forgot to include another tid bit of information though.
the variable j goes up to 6 and the tempcounter goes up to 5 before spitting out segmentation fault.

Comment: Of course it doen not work: I stop reading when I find the first error. And I stopped at about 25% of the code. The nesting looks starage, and so does the `for (i = 0; i <= num; i++)`. My estimate time is that there are five...ten course errors in the other 75% of the source.

Comment: Ok so let me try to clarify this for me.......
With the output I have from the top of this post, I want to create an array of size 4 of NameValue struct.. and you said my code didn't that before but "pairs = malloc(num * sizeof *pairs)" that one does?

Comment: There are too many (possible) errors. Best thing is to build up the thing step-by-step, and test it step-by-step. We cannot teach you programming in one hour.

Comment: `fread(string, sizeof (char), 300, stdin);` does not necessarily put a `\0` at the end.  Use `fgets(string, sizeof string, stdin)`

Comment: I figured it out. The segmentation fault was coming from me not initializing the member variables inside the struct. (forgive me if I'm not using the proper terms for C)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured it out. Not only did I need to malloc the pairs but I also need to malloc the member variables inside each malloc's pairs.

I ended up using my tempCounter to see how many characters I needed and malloc'd the correct amount for the member variables.

Answer (score 0):

You never null terminate the string `tempName`. Then you try printing it here:

```
if (string[j] == ':') {
    tempCounter = 0;
    **printf("~~~~tempName\n is: %s", tempName);**
    break;
}
```

Comment: I removed it to test before and I forgot to put it back in. It still gives the segmentation fault though. Do you have any other ideas?

Answer (score 0):

Strings in C are a series of characters in memory, terminated by a null byte (i.e. `'\0'`). You're copying bytes into a buffer, but you never yourself create this null terminator, hence `printf` runs off the end and into undefined memory.

Instead, at the end of the while loop, you need to assign the next character in `tempName` to `'\0'`, probably inside the while loop just before printing it.

Before `tempCounter = 0`, just put `tempName[tempCounter] = '\0';`.

Comment: Sorry! I had that line in there but I forgot I removed it to test. It still gives the segmentation fault though. Do you have any other ideas?

Comment: @Recur Check if you're out of bounds. Step trough every line of your code.

Comment: What should I use to step through? I don't think I can use NetBeans to debug because I have to pipe output from one program into mine.